# Rails 3 ActiveRecord: Order by count on association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model named `Song`. I also have a model named `Listen`. A `Listen` `belongs_to :song`, and a song `:has_many listens` (can be listen to many times).

In my model I want to define a method `self.top` which should return the top 5 songs listened to the most. How can I achieve that using the `has_many` relation?

I'm using Rails 3.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Using [named scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
class Song
  has_many :listens
  scope :top5,
    select("songs.id, OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED, count(listens.id) AS listens_count").
    joins(:listens).
    group("songs.id").
    order("listens_count DESC").
    limit(5)

Song.top5 # top 5 most listened songs
```

Comment: SUre, remove the limit statement from the scope definition, then in controller call like so: `Song.where(:user_id => current_user.id).top.limit(5)`

Comment: Thank you. I had to add group("songs.id") between joins and order. :)

Comment: Since user_id is an attribute of listens and not songs, I ended up throwing it into a def and having a user parameter. Then I added this after joins(): where(user == nil ? "" : "listens.user_id = #{user.id}"). Thank you so much for your help. :D
`

Comment: `where(user.nil? ? '' : *["listens.user_id = ?", user.id])` is better because it escapes

Comment: I guess you are using MySQL. In Postgres you need to aggregate all attributes: .group("listens.id,songs.#{Song.column_names.join(",songs.")}")

Comment: Excellent answer; is there a way to do this where you can receive the association results, AND the rest of the Songs?  So that in an Index, for example, the songs with top listens are at the top, but songs without any listens are still listed?

Comment: @rcd just remove the `limit(5)` clause

Comment: Is there a way to extend this scope by only counting the listens which were created in the last 24 hours?

Comment: Ok, I guess I found a solution: `Work.select('works.name, count(impressions.id) AS impressions_count').joins(:impressions).where('impressions.created_at >= ?', Time.now - 1.day).group('works.name').order('impressions_count DESC')` Is this correct?

Comment: @clyfe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669484/how-to-get-value-using-join-table-with-different-values/56680298#56680298

Answer (score 33):

Even better, use `counter_cache` which will be faster because you'll only because using one table in your query

Here is your song class:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listens

  def self.top
    order('listens_count DESC').limit(5)
  end
end
```

Then, your listen class:

```
class Listen < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song, counter_cache: true
end
```

Make sure you add a migration:

```
add_column :comments, :likes_count, :integer, default: 0
```

Bonus points, add test:

```
describe '.top' do
  it 'shows most listened songs first' do
    song_one = create(:song)
    song_three = create(:song, listens_count: 3)
    song_two = create(:song, listens_count: 2)

    popular_songs = Song.top

    expect(popular_songs).to eq [song_three, song_two, song_one]
  end
end
```

---

Or, if you want to go with the above method, here it is a bit more simply, and using a class method rather than `scope`

```
def self.top
    select('comments.*, COUNT(listens.id) AS listens_count').
      joins(:listens).                                                   
      group('comments.id').
      order('listens_count DESC').
      limit(5)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me about counter_cache. Haven't seen that before. :) But it won't work for me since I also need to only include listens which belong to a specific user, meaning I am stuck with some more complex queries.

Comment: are you forgetting a dot at the end of select or is it not needed?

Comment: Did you mean "listens_count" rather than "likes_count" in the migration?

Comment: Neal, I have a similar problem which is a bit more complex so I just can't figure it out. Could you take a look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929227/rails-complex-order-by-with-argument

Answer (score 0):

For rails 4.x try this if your rows without any association matters:

```
scope :order_by_my_association, lambda {
    select('comments.*, COUNT(listens.id) AS listens_total')
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN listens ON listens.comment_id = comments.id")
    .group('comments.id')
    .order("listens_total DESC")
  }
```