# Rails - Passing a specific column to query by count of an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a rails app with "recipes" model. Recipe can be liked ("like" model) by a user. What I'd like to achieve (eventually) is to sort the list of the recipes on the recipes-index page by the number of likes.

I've seen numerous threads but the two that guided me the most were:

[Rails 3 ActiveRecord: order and group by association count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798105/rails-3-activerecord-order-and-group-by-association-count)

[Rails order by results count of has_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996618/rails-order-by-results-count-of-has-many-association)

I've got so far that I have an SQL-query that produces list of the recipes with the count of their likes:

```
SELECT recipes.name, COUNT(likes.id)
FROM recipes
LEFT JOIN likes on recipes.id = likes.recipe_id
GROUP BY recipes.name
ORDER BY COUNT(likes.id) DESC;
```

However, when "translating" it to something ActiveRecord can understand, I'm running into troubles.

I've concluded that using Recipe.joins(:likes) or Recipe.left_joins(:likes) passes all columns specified in "recipes", which leads to the following error:

"Column "recipes.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function...".

Now, as I need to pass recipes.name and COUNT(likes.id) only, I used select:

```
Recipe.select("recipes.name, COUNT(likes.id)").joins(:likes).group("recipes.name").order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC")
```

And that's where I'm stranded as it produces this:

ActiveRecord::Relation [Recipe id: nil, name: "Scrambled eggz", Recipe id: nil, name: "Soup", Recipe id: nil, name: "Nutella pancakes"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct. Please note that it use `Recipe` model class, which does not contains your custom field in its Class. If your query is

```
Recipe.select("COUNT(likes.id)").joins(:likes).group("recipes.name").order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC")
```

It will show you

```
ActiveRecord::Relation [Recipe id: nil, Recipe id: nil, Recipe id: nil]
```

However, You still can access your custom fields, the returned data hold it for you to use. You just need to give it a name to call it. Also, You can use that custom field to order, please don't direct order `COUNT`

```
recipes = Recipe.select("COUNT(likes.id) as total_likes").joins(:likes).group("recipes.name").order("total_likes DESC")
recipe.first.total_likes # TOTAL LIKE of first recipe
```

Comment: Why should one avoid direct ordering by count?

Answer (score 1):

```
Recipe.joins("LEFT JOIN likes ON recipes.id = likes. recipe_id").group("recipes.id").order("COUNT(likes.id) ASC")
```

ActiveRecord parsing expects the returned resultset to have the columns that the original model has(Or a subset of columns).

When selecting a subset of the original columns, ActiveRecord nullifies all the other columns while parsing it in an ActiveRecord object/relation

Comment: please elaborate a bit. What does all these functions do and why does this work. Just dropping a line of code is not an awesome answer. Please educate future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you if you want to it in active record query:

```
Recipe.left_joins(:likes).group(:id).order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC")
```

****Warning for the *JOIN*:****

```
Recipe.joins(:likes).group(:id).order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC")
```

This query will only return the recipes which have likes. If there are any recipes that don't have any likes, doing ***JOINS*** won't get you those.