# Filter model association count by date?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models: `User`, `Call`.

A `User` `has_many` `Calls`.

A Call has a column: `created_at`

I need to filter the users **who have the most calls** in the last 'x' days.

I'm here so far:

```
User.includes(:calls).limit(10).where("created_at > ?", Time.now - 20.days)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.includes(:calls).where("calls.created_at > ?", Time.now - 20.days).limit(10)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't do: "who have the most calls".

Comment: Please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association

Answer (score 0):

You should go from Calls here, not from Users.
Something like:

```
Call.where("created_at > ?", Time.now - 20.days).group(:user_id).order("count(user_id) DESC").count("user_id")
```

As a result you get a hash with key - user_id and value - number of calls