# Return Table ordered by count of column ACTIVERECORD Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count, rails-activerecord

My Ruby on Rails method is as follows:

```
def top_posts
    Post.order('count(:comments)').first(3)
end
```

What I am trying to do is return the first three posts ordered by the number of comments on each post.

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Post.first(3).sort! { |a,b| b.comments.count <=> a.comments.count}
```