# Find parent record with most children (has many relationship)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Using rails 4 and postgres 9.1, how do I write a query to find the parent record (or records in the event of a tie) which have the most children given a standard has_many :through relationship (parents have many children and children belong to a parent).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 ActiveRecord: order by count on association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association)

Comment: Thanks @infused - the link helped.  I searched for about 20 minutes for max associations and synonyms, but didn't think to look for ordering by count.  Will leave this up incase someone else uses the same terms as me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
Parent.select('parents.id, COUNT(children.id) AS children_count').joins(:children).group('parents.id').order('children_count DESC').take(1).first
```

infused's link provides a few alternatives.