# Order Rails Active Record by Count in Another Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a comment model which has likes associated with it. I keep the likes in a separate table and the comment model has_many likes. However, I want to order the comments by most popular and I do not know how to do an active directory query to return the order I want. I have tried:

```
Comment.order(:likes.count)
```

This isn't working. Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 ActiveRecord: order by count on association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association)

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me currently with Rails 5:

```
Comment.joins(:likes)
  .select('comments.*, count(likes) as like_count')
  .group('comments.id')
  .order('like_count desc')
```

It even adds a `like_count` attribute to each returned `comment`, so you can call `comment.like_count`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Comment.joins(:likes).order('count(likes.*) desc')
```