# No such column on ordering by association count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm having some issues with trying to order a model by association count. The method I'm using was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696088) and it works in console and whenever I pause it by using byebug. Other times it doesn't execute the select statement at all and just tries to do the group and order. This is my class:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :course_videos, foreign_key: :course_id
has_many :videos, through: :course_videos

scope :ordered_by_video_count, -> {
joins(:videos)
    .select("courses.*, count(videos.id) as video_count")
    .group("courses.id")
    .order("video_count desc")
}
end
```

And the exact error I'm getting is this:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: video_count: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, courses.id AS courses_id FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "course_videos" ON "course_videos"."course_id" = "courses"."id" INNER JOIN "videos" ON "videos"."id" = "course_videos"."video_id" GROUP BY courses.id  ORDER BY video_count desc
```

Thanks!

Stefan

Comment: For some reason it's not respecting the `as`, you can see that in the sql error `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all`.  You could change the order to be `count_all` rather than `video_count`.  If not you're going to need to work out why the as isn't being respected.  Maybe try wrapping them in quotes?  I don't use sqlite but a quick google shows tutorials having them, I'm not sure if sqlite needs them so might do nothing.  `.select("courses.*, count(videos.id) as 'video_count'")`

Comment: @japed Neither the count_all ordering nor the quotes did anything. SQLite is only for the dev env but postgres seems to be skipping it as well.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it makes a difference, but try

```
.order(video_count: :desc)
```

that's the syntax I alway use.

Comment: actually, the problem is that you need to use a cache counter. Maybe check this out: http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/

Comment: While I could indeed use that, I'd love to know why this SQL isn't working in order to not make the same mistake next time. Thanks though! And the video_count: :desc didn't change it. The entire select statement seems to be overlooked by Rails sometimes.