# rails complex order_by with argument

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, sql-order-by

I have a rails app. I would like to display user profiles ordered by the number of the common tasks they have with the current user. Every task has one assigner and one executor. The number should include both the executed_tasks and assigned_tasks for the same user. So for example if current_user assigned 5 tasks to User4 and User4 assigned 3 tasks to current_user then this number would be 8.

My main problem is that I don't know how to use the given user as arg for the count. Should I do in the model somehow or when I set the instance variable (@users) in the controller?

task.rb

```
belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"

scope :between, -> (assigner_id, executor_id) do
  where("(tasks.assigner_id = ? AND tasks.executor_id = ?) OR (tasks.assigner_id = ? AND tasks.executor_id = ?)", assigner_id, executor_id, executor_id, assigner_id)
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id", dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to execute this with a single SQL query to improve performance, you could do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def assigners
    Task.where(executor_id: id).select('assigner_id AS user_id')
  end

  def executors
    Task.where(assigner_id: id).select('executor_id AS user_id')
  end

  def relations_sql
    "((#{assigners.to_sql}) UNION ALL (#{executors.to_sql})) AS relations"
  end

  def ordered_relating_users
    User.joins("RIGHT OUTER JOIN #{relations_sql} ON relations.user_id = users.id")
      .group(:id)
      .order('COUNT(relations.user_id) DESC')
  end
end
```

As the comment requests for taking into account the unrelating users, and limit to 6, it's a little bit trickier, since we use `FULL_OUTER_JOIN`.The edited function would be:

```
def ordered_relating_users
  User.joins("FULL OUTER JOIN #{relations_sql} ON relations.user_id = users.id")
      .where.not(id: id)
      .group(:id)
      .order('COUNT(relations.user_id) DESC')
      .limit(6)
end
```

Comment: Hoang, how can I call it in the controller or in the view?

Comment: Just call `given_user.ordered_relating_users`

Comment: Hoang, it's working! Thx. Could you suggest me some resources where I can read about this topic? I don't get it totally, so I would do some reading on it, but it's hard to find good articles.

Comment: Hoang, one more question. This only takes into account the users that sby has already at least one task with. So if there was a new user he would see nothing. For them I would like to show the rest of the users. I limit the shown users to 6 at the moment. If there is more than 6 users the given user has task with then this query works fine. If there is 0 user the given user has task with then I can just use an if else statement. But let's say there is 2 users the given user has tasks with and I would like to show him 4 extra users to fill the gap. How could I do that?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar: it's just the plain sql-based solution that I thought of, used nested subquery in `from` clause, you could refer here: http://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/subquery-in-from-clause.php

First off, find all other user ids relating to the specific user A to a view, that means assigners (executor is A) and executors (assigner is A), since the column names differ, you need to normalize it (to user_id for example) and join it together using union all.

Then join user table with that view (right outer join to keep all the relation records) and order by group count.

Comment: If you want to take into account all users, just replace `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` with `FULL OUTER JOIN`, to limit the number of users just add `.limit(6)` to `ordered_relating_users` function.