# Rails 4 ActiveRecord order by count of association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

There's a view where I want to display the contents of

for example:

```
recipe.user.name 
recipe.name
recipe.picture
recipe.created_at
```

sorted by

```
recipe.likes.count
```

Controller:

```
@recipes_by_likes = Recipe.likes_count.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Model:

```
Recipe has_many :likes
```

and

```
Like belongs_to :recipe
```

Scope:

```
scope :likes_count, -> { 
  select('recipes.*, COUNT(likes.id) AS likes_count').
  joins(:likes).
  order('likes_count DESC')
}
```

but that gives me

```
SELECT  recipes.*, COUNT(likes.id) AS likes_count 
FROM "recipes" 
INNER JOIN "likes" ON "likes"."recipe_id" = "recipes"."id"  
ORDER BY "recipes"."created_at" DESC, likes_count DESC 
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

which returns only 1 (wrong) result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3 ActiveRecord: Order by count on association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Query

You should not count likes by their `id` since it is always unique and will always return 1, instead by the `recipe_id` which is the same in the likes associated with a certain recipe.

```
scope :likes_count, -> { 
  select('recipes.*, COUNT(likes.recipe_id) AS likes_count')
  .joins(:likes)
  .group('recipes.id')
  .order('likes_count DESC')
}
```

### 2. Counter Cache Method

Also you can use a `counter_cache`

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe, counter_cache: true
end
```

And add a column to `Recipe` model

```
add_column :recipes, :likes_count, :integer, default: 0
```

Comment: getting:

    SELECT  recipes.*, 
    COUNT(likes.recipe_id) AS likes_count 
    FROM "recipes" 
    INNER JOIN "likes" ON "likes"."recipe_id" = "recipes"."id"  
    ORDER BY "recipes"."created_at" DESC, likes_count DESC 
    LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0

but only 1 result

Comment: Why is there a `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`? Anyways try to add `group("likes.recipe_id")` to your above query and tell me what you get.

Comment: SELECT  recipes.*, COUNT(likes.recipe_id) AS likes_count FROM "recipes" INNER JOIN "likes" ON "likes"."recipe_id" = "recipes"."id" GROUP
BY likes.recipe_id  ORDER BY "recipes"."created_at" DESC, likes_count DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0 .. 7 results (except of recipes with no likes) in wrong order

Comment: Updated the answer. Also added the `counter_cache` method

Comment: added counter_cache as you described - works like a charm!